# WordPress Database error shows when Apostrophe sign is used (Unbelievable)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't believe it.In word press Post editor when I put **Bank's** it shows a huge Data base error but when I just use **Bank** .No error. Post looks fine.
Can Wordpress posts do not accept **Apostrophes**??

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '**s%' OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%on-line%' OR
>   postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%websit**' at line 1]

```
SELECT posts.*,
       postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS posts,
     wp_postmeta AS postmeta
WHERE posts.post_type IN ('page',
                          'post')
  AND posts.post_status='publish'
  AND posts.ID = postmeta.post_id
  AND posts.ID <> 361
  AND postmeta.meta_key = 'cprp_tags'
  AND (postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%mmgs%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%management%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%ii%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%iii%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%scale%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%rs%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%middle%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%grade%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%years%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%application%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%post%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%online%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%candidates%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%recruitment%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%bank%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%special%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%banking%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%fees%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%payment%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%graduation%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%qualification%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%www.sbi.co.in%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%selection%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%registration%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%emoluments%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%executive%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%state%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%india%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%apply%'
       OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%bank's%' OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%on-line%' OR postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%website%') AND postmeta.post_id NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'cprp_exclude_from_posts')
```

Comment: Since there are lots of hints that that SQL query is coming from a plugin (cp-related-posts), I wouldn't be too quick to blame WordPress.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if one of the leading blogging platforms wasn't able to get simple SQL injection right it would have disappeared from the map long ago, hacked down to dust. You must have added something to the stock installation.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are seeing is coming from a bug in the [CP Related Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cp-related-posts/) plugin. You can see the error on [this line](https://github.com/wp-plugins/cp-related-posts/blob/master/cp-related-posts.php#L698) where the `$tags` array is passed into the query using `implode()` without addressing SQL compatibility by passing it through a function like `$wpdb->prepare()`. When you save a tag with a single quote in it, such as `Bank's` it breaks the SQL query being run by the plugin, resulting in the error you see.

The development of the plugin seems to be active, so I suggest opening a ticket on their support page.